# Complicated Percentage Question

Tags: percentages

In a certain town some people were affected by a ’flu’ epidemic. In the first
month $20$% of the population contracted the flu whilst $80$% were healthy.
In the following month $20$% of the sick people recovered and $20$% of the
healthy people contracted the disease.
What fraction of the population is healthy at the end of the second month?

Can someone help me tackle this problem as I am struggling to proceed.

Comment: Hint: suppose there are $100$ people in the town, and manually work it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The population consists of those who are sick and those who are healthy.

*First month*:

- $20\%$ of the population are sick
- $80\%$ of the population are healthy

*Second month*:

- $20\%$ of the sick are now healthy

  $\implies$ $20\%$ of $20\%$ of the population 

  $\quad\quad$ are added to the healthy group 

  $\quad\quad$and removed from the sick group
   

  $\implies$ $4\%$ of the population has shifted from sick to healthy
- $20\%$ of the healthy are now sick 
  $\implies 20\%$ of $80\%$ of the population 
  $\quad\quad$are added to the sick group

  $\quad\quad$and removed from the healthy group 

  $\implies 16\%$ of the population has shifted from healthy to sick.

$\therefore$ Healthy Population $= 80\% + 4\% - 16\% = 68\%$

Answer (score 2):

$\frac15$  (20%) of $\frac45$ (80% of affected are still affected) plus $\frac45$ (healthy after first month) of $\frac15 $ (20% became sick): 
$$\frac15\cdot \frac45+\frac45\cdot\frac15 = \frac8{25} = 32\%$$
 32% are affected;  68% are not.

Answer (score -2):

$20\%$ of the $20\%$ of the population that was sick became healthy.

$80\%$ of the $80\%$ of the population that was healthy stayed healthy.

Multiply then add.  It's not that complicated.